# intl-messageformat: Ignore escape sequences for message syntax chars

Tags: javascript, internationalization, intl

is there any way change the behaviour for parsing quotes when using [Intl MessageFormat](https://formatjs.io/docs/intl-messageformat)?

[This section in the docs](https://formatjs.io/docs/intl-messageformat#features) says:

> Supports escape sequences for message syntax chars, e.g.: "'{foo}'" will output: "{foo}" in the formatted output instead of interpreting it as a foo argument.

---

#### Default behaviour

```
const msg = new IntlMessageFormat("Email: '{email}'").format({email: "test@email.com"}) 
// -> Email: {email}
```

#### Desired behaviour

```
const msg = new IntlMessageFormat("Email: '{email}'").format({email: "test@email.com"}) 
// -> Email: 'test@email.com'
```

How can I accomplish the desired behaviour? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In ICU string you'd use two single quotations `''` to escape it.

```js
const msg = new IntlMessageFormat("Email: ''{email}''").format({email: "test@email.com"})
```

Answer (score -1):

Leave off the single-quote characters:

```
const message = new IntlMessageFormat("Email: {email}").format({email: "test@email.com"});
```

The documentation you quoted is about how to *prevent* the behavior that you want. If you don't want to prevent it, don't do what that documentation instructs.